# can not login with laravel attempt return false everytime

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

**Here is my SessionController**

```
 public function store()
{
    //Attempt to authenticate user
    if(! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))){
        return back();
    }

    return redirect()->home();
}
```

Password populated with plain text, and am inputting correct email and password, but its not logging me in :(

**here is my route**

```
    Route::get('/login','SessionController@create');
    Route::post('/login','SessionController@store');

    Looking forward for your respected answers and comment.
```

Comment: `Password populated with plain text` - there's your issue. Use `tinker` and create a hash for your password like this: `Hash::make('password');` Then copy and paste that value into your DB.

Comment: Thanks bro, i forgot to bcrypt() my password field in register view. thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You Should also Need to Pass `(Request $request)` in store function.
Also `bcrypt()` Your Password.
Hope this may help you.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Attempt to authenticate user
    if(! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))){
        return back();
    }

    return redirect()->home();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check with this code:

```
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;

 public function store (Request $request) {

 $username = $request->input('email');
 $password = $request->input('password');

 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {

   return redirect()->intended('admin_dashboard');

 }
 else {

   Session::flash('message', 'User name or password is incorrect!');
   return redirect('/')->with('message', 'User name or password is incorrect!');

  }
```

}

Use the same routes which you used.